# NUM_ROWS Zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, frameworks

I would like to know how to implement a query using num_rows ZEND 1.12

```
  $db = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();
  $db->setFetchMode(Zend_Db::FETCH_ASSOC);
  $select = new Zend_Db_Select($db);

  $select = $db->select()
        ->from('album', array('id', 'nombre'));

  $result = $select->query();

  $rows = $result->fetch();
```

This code returns incomplete data. I do not know if this is well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$dbAdapter = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();
$dbAdapter->setFetchMode(Zend_Db::FETCH_ASSOC);

/** @var Zend_Db_Select $select */
$select = $dbAdapter->select();

$select->from(
    'album', 
    array(
        'id', 
        'nombre'
    )
);

//get the rowset
/** @var Zend_Db_Table_Rowset $rows */
$rows = $dbAdapter->fetchAll($select);

//get the number of rows returned from the rows object
$num_rows = $rows->count(); //OR count($rows)
```

But be aware, if you use a limit in your query, you will not get the total number of rows in the db table.

```
//$select->limit(100); //will return 100 or less
```

**If you want to get only the number of rows in a db table, use this:**

```
//get only a single columns value! (there has to be only one column in the select)

$select = $dbAdapter->select();

$select->from(
    'album', 
    array(
        'COUNT(*) AS num_rows'
    )
);
//$select->where("nombre LIKE CONCAT('?','%')",array($search));
//$select->where("status > 0");

$num_rows = $dbAdapter->fetchCol($select);
```